# mysql conditional query inner join

Tags: mysql, case, inner-join

I have the following tables:
quotes
quote_items
old_products
new_products

```
quotes.id = quote_items.quote_id
old_products.id = quote_items.old_product_id
new_products.id = quote_items.new_product_id
```

I have this query which works out the average % saved:

```
Select ROUND((sum(q.`old_kwh`) - sum(`p`.`new_kwh`))/sum(q.`old_kwh`)*100) as 
percentage_saved from quotes 
inner join quote_items
on quotes.id = `quote_items`.quote_id
INNER JOIN `new_products` p 
ON p.id = new_product_id
inner join old_products q
ON q.id = old_product_id
```

**
**EDIT**
**

The problem is this:
for certain old_products, 'old_kwh' = 0. In that case:

I need to calculate the kwh from the quote_items_input table where:

```
quote_items_input.quote_item_id = quote_items.id
```

[image: quote_items_input table]

In this case,

```
old_kwh = (old_Litre_measurement.input_value) * (Number of uses per day.input_value) * (avg shower time.input_value)
        = 20*2*10
        = 400
```

So if 'old_products'.old_kwh = 0 for a specific quote, the above equation must be substituted in its place when summing that particular old_kwh.

**
**End EDIT**
**

How can I add this to the above query? I was looking at CASE conditions with mysql, but have had no luck so far.

Any help would be awesome
Thanks

Comment: I removed my answer. In your field list, use case to prevents division by zero.

Comment: Is there No-one that can help me with this?! Im really struggling

Comment: Im totally stuck here. Can someone please shed some light for me. Is this query even possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
CASE q.old_kwh
    WHEN 0 THEN ROUND((sum(quote_items_input.input value) - sum(`p`.`new_kwh`))/sum(quote_items_input.input value)*100)
    ELSE ROUND((sum(q.`old_kwh`) - sum(`p`.`new_kwh`))/sum(q.`old_kwh`)*100)
END as percentage_saved 
FROM quotes 
INNER JOIN quote_items
on quotes.id = `quote_items`.quote_id
INNER JOIN quote_items_input
on quote_items_input.quote_item_id = quote_items.id
INNER JOIN `new_products` p 
ON p.id = new_product_id
INNER JOIN old_products q
ON q.id = old_product_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure I'm understanding the CASE section. If q.old_kwh = 0, 'i'd need to use the value of quote_items_input.input value in place of old_kwh in the SUM equation.

Comment: I've updated my answer according to your comment. Please check it.

Comment: Thanks Sarwar, its working but returning the wrong value, which is my fault, I forgot to mention something in the query. I need to show an a table example for coherence sake, how can I show one?

Comment: You are welcome. But please provide your table schema and some sample data so that I can look into the matter closely.

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but how do i get them in a readable format for posting on here?

Comment: @mrcurious: You can post the schema in simple text format/image format.

Comment: Please see my edit above with example. Hope you can understand what I'm trying to do. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any suggestions with regards to my updated query?

Comment: @mrcurious: It's going to be more complex since you are putting your desired value in row instead of column (which is standard, I agree). I will give a try after office hour. Thanks

Comment: @Sarawr: Im really struggling here Sarwar, any chance you have a solution for me?

Comment: @mrcurious: actually, I thought what to do when old_kwh=0, but in that case, I don't know how to calculate here. if the value is in the column instead of row, then I can give a solution. but here, it really complicated :(

Comment: Ok thanks for you help thus far Sarwar. hopefully someone will be able to help me out.